# Briefly, main function behavior - multiple classes in one source file

Tags: java, eclipse

Given a Java source file named as **TestMainFunction.java**

1.) As most of us would know, a Java file name must be the class name which contains the main function

See the below simple code (in a single file named as mentioned above) which executes perfectly and prints `ClassOne`.

```
public class TestMainFunction {}

class ClassOne {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("ClassOne");
    }
}
```

2.) When there is more than one class with a main function in a single file, Eclipse prompts the user to choose the class to run.

See the below simple code (single file named as mentioned above) which executes perfectly and prints the class name as we have chosen from the Eclipse promt.

```
public class TestMainFunction {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("TestMainFunction");
    }
}

class ClassOne {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("ClassOne");
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("ClassTwo");
    }
}
```

All the above will work as I mentioned. **It will create separate .class file for every class**. The same behavior applies even when using inner classes.

But what exactly is happening here? How does Eclipse know which class to launch when multiple classes are present in one source file? Can any one explain it? Explaining this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It knows it because, as you said, it prompts the user to choose the one you want to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As most of you would know, a Java file name must be the class name
>   which contains the main function

This is incorrect, and I believe the source of your confusion. A Java source file is only allowed to have one public class, and it ***must*** have the same name (minus the extension) as it's containing file. A given Java source file though, may contain as many non-public class files as desired, with the only constraint being that [their names are valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). Note that you can have a class with the same name as its containing source file (minus the extension) *that is not public*! Also note that it's generally considered bad practice to have multiple top-level (non-nested) classes in a single Java source file.

The second assumption you may have is that only one class in a source file is allowed to have a main function. This is simply untrue. You can add a main function to every single one of your class files - the only one that matters is the one you specify to the JVM when your application is being launched.

So given your scenario - a source file with multiple class files (one of them public), where each class has a main method, the following applies:

- When you invoke the Run command in Eclipse on this file, Eclipse will detect that there is more than one eligible class to be run, and will prompt you to select one of those class. It will then build a 'Run Profile' for the selected class, that launches *just that class*. You can actually see the profile Eclipse builds via the Run->Debug Configurations menu.
- When compiling this source file externally, it will generate multiple .class files (not just one). The classes had no relation to each other save being in the same source file, and you would explicitly select the .class you want to launch in the JVM.

i.e:

```
java TestMainFunction
java ClassOne
java ClassTwo
```

Comment: @JBNizet - Agreed, and incorporated.